# Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY shows 0 - 12 format

Tags: java

If I use the following code, the program dosen't work. The 'Hour_Of_Day' format is wrong. Why?

```
try {
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        // Schedule to run every Sunday in midnight
        timer.schedule(new StarteProzesse(), today.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS));
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by hour of day format is wrong ?

Comment: your code (except `new StarteProzesse()`) works ok, what problem are you experiencing? any errors? Stacktrace? **is `StarteProzesse` a `TimerTask`?????**

Comment: The Problem is, that if i write for example '2' or '3', all numbers bigger than '12', Calendar not working and the code runs despite the time. But if i write '13-0' everything works fine

Comment: Please read the **Add rule 1** of [java.util.Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#time_resolution)